# React useContext() performance, useContext inside custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-hooks, react-context

I used a structure using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). It is based on a global [Context](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that contains a combination of reducers (as in the Redux).
Also, I widely use [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) to separate logic.
I have a hook that contains asynchronous API requests and it has become quite cumbersome and I have the opportunity to split almost every function of this hook into other hooks, but each of these functions uses a global context (more precisely - dispatch from useReducer()).

#### So, questions:

1. Is it ok to use useContext() in every hook who needs it?
2. How will it affect performance if, for example, I create 10 custom hooks that use useContext() internally and use them in the component.

#### Example:

providers/Store.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const StoreContext = createContext();

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  /**
   * Store that contains combined reducers.
   */
  const store = useReducer(rootReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

hooks/useStore.js

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { StoreContext } from '../providers';

export const useStore = () => useContext(StoreContext);
```

hooks/useFoo.js

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useStore } from './useStore';

export const useFoo = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = useStore();

  const doFoo = useCallback(
    async params => {
      dispatch(actions.request());

      try {
        const res = await SomeService.getSomething(params);
        dispatch(actions.add(res));
        dispatch(actions.success());
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(actions.failure());
      }
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  return { doFoo };
};
```

hooks/useBar.js

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useStore } from './useStore';

export const useBar = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = useStore();

  const doBar = useCallback(
    async params => {
      dispatch(actions.request());

      try {
        const res = await SomeService.getSomething(params);
        dispatch(actions.success());
        dispatch(actions.add(res));
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(actions.failure());
      }
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  return { doBar };
};
```

hooks/useNext.js

```
...
import { useStore } from './useStore';

export const useNext = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = useStore();

  ...
};
```

components/SomeComponent.js

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  // use context
  const [store, dispatch] = useStore();

  // and here is the context
  const { doFoo } = useFoo();

  // and here
  const { doBar } = useBar();

  // and here
  useNext();

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={doFoo}>Foo</Button>
      <Button onClick={doBar}>Bar</Button>
      // the flag is also available in another component
      {store.isLoading && <Spin />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, hooks can reference a state queue owned by component. ([Under the hood of React’s hooks system - Eytan Manor](https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba)
)

`useContext` is just to reference a global state from the relative Context Provider. There is almost no overhead from `useContext` as you are concerned.